# cant connect to ubuntu hotspot 22.10 through the QR code from my android 12 or iphone

Tags: hot-spot

I am trying to connect my phone to the ubuntu hotspot , but it keeps saying in the phone after reading the QRcode, that is not connection and I should check it. After that the hotspot in ubuntu close and desactivate it.

I have try different solutions with firewall and so on. NOthing works. It has benn working before in ubuntu 20 without any problem.

Thanks foryour help

Comment: Please provide release details clearly; desktop & server systems are *year.month* in format, though specialist a *specialist* server *flavor* with the *year* format does exist. You mention Ubuntu 20, so it was a *headless* Ubuntu Core 20 server system?

Comment: There was no release in 2022-January (22.01), so do you mean Ubuntu 22.10 (ie. the 2022-October release). Either way please correct your question; and be aware 20 & 20.04 are different Ubuntu products (20 is a *flavor* of 20.04 Server)

Comment: BEEN USING uBUNTU lTS  20 AND NOW i AM IN 22.10. hOPE YOU CAN HELP WITH THAT INFO NOW, @guiverc

Comment: @yop accidental capslock?

Comment: I just found that the problem is with the QR code of the hotspot active. It doesnt get connected through it. But if I wait for the phone to reach the wifi, and then write the password, it works perfectly.